# unable to access the SENSOR_SERVICE inside fragment

Tags: android, fragment

This used to be like

```
sSensorManager = (SensorManager)this.getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
```

in an activity , now in fragment I am making it like below

```
sSensorManager = (SensorManager)rootView.getContext().getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
```

And there I get redline below SENSOR_SERVICE like below

```
SENSOR_SERVICE cannot be resolved to a variable
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this in `Fragment`

```
sSensorManager = (SensorManager)getActivity().getSystemService(getActivity().SENSOR_SERVICE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Does not matter where you are, you access like a `static Constant`

```
sSensorManager = (SensorManager)rootView.getContext().getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
```